# I have problem with pivot in Maya and Blender

Tags: blender, maya, mel

I have pivot problem. I am setting, a pivot in Maya (for a car wheel) and when I import the `fbx` of the model in Blender, pivot point is resetting on null.

Any solution about that problem?

Comment: Is this question about programming with Blender or is it about Blender itself? If it's about Blender, see the http://blender.stackexchange.com Stack Exchange site for more Blender-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Save your wheel inside a new group and position a group's pivot to a desired place. It'd work when you open your file in Blender. Here's MEL equivalent for Maya Script Editor to test group's pivot point:

```
polySphere -r 2 -sx 20 -sy 20 -ax 0 1 0 ;
doGroup 0 1 1 ;
move -r 0 5 0 group1.scalePivot group1.rotatePivot ;
```

Also, when exporting from Maya it's better to choose `DAE_FBX export` file type.